# Remove a pair of brackets without using plugins

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I am looking for a way to remove a pair of brackets in the insertion mode without plugins. It's like

```
(|)
```

When I press the delete key only the first bracket get deleted

```
|)
```

But I want to auto-remove the second one when I press the delete key if there is no content in the pair of brackets. And I want to achieve this without plugins.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24757/18609, some of the answers include an `<expr>` mapping for `<BS>`, which is how I'd suggest you'd handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the cursor in or on the parentheses, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> combined with <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to delete the parentheses and any text contained within.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> lets you execute one normal mode command, then return to insert mode. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> deletes a block text object, including `(` and `)`. This also works with an empty block `()`.

**Example**:

Say I am in insert mode with the following text, with the cursor position indicated by `█`:

```
here is (some text█in ~parentheses~)
```

After hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, you would then be left in insert mode with the following text:

```
here is █
```

You could even wrap it in a mapping if its a functionality you would like to use often (`<Leader><BS>` in this example):

```
inoremap <Leader><BS> <C-o>dab
```

There are analogs for `[]` and `{}` blocks too.

**See**:

```
:h i_CTRL-O
:h a(
:h text-objects
```

Comment: But the content should stay...?!

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches to detect weither we are within an empty pair.

- The simple one: `getline('.')[col('.')-2 : col('.')] == '()'` that's simple to understand. To support more pairs we can test a regex instead: `getline('.')[col('.')-2 : col('.')] =~ '\V()\\|[]\\|{}\\|<>\\|$$'`
- The one that supports multicharacters pairs like `<del></del>`. Instead of playing with a strip of the current line, we can use `/\%c`. This time it's easier to maintain a list of pairs activated for the current filetype as a list, apply some transformation on that list, and we have our regex. e.g.

  ```
  let b:pairs = [['(', ')'], ['\\(', '\\)'], ['<', '>'], ['<del>', '</del>']

  " excerpt from lh-brackets
  let regex = let regex = '\V\('.join(map(copy(crt_pairs), 'join(v:val,"\\%'.col('.').'c")'), '\|').'\)'
  return getline('.') =~ regex
  ```

  Of course this `b:pairs`  maintenance is best done with .... a plugin that keeps tracks of the recorded pairs for the current filetype.

Now, regarding the delete part. It's about executing `<c-g>U<bs>`  and `<del>`  as many times as required each. The `i_CTRL-U`  is required to support redo as `<bs>`  moves the cursor. In case of multi-byte characters implied in the pairs, don't forget to count the length with the right function.